# HTML email is not displaying properly when viewed from outlook.com in the firefox, IE and chrome browsers

Tags: html, html-email, email-client, outlook.com

I am testing an html email in litmus. It is rendering perfectly in all browsers and clients except for outlook.com on firefox, chrome and IE. I am getting these weird borders and my page layout is slightly thrown off. My A tags also break in outlook.com. I'm new to html email development and this one has me stumped. Any help leading me in the right direction is appreciated.

[Here is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTbvJ.png)

[Here is how it is rendering in outlook.com(firefiox, chrome, IE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYz13.png)

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    .social span{
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<center class="wrapper">
    <div class="webkit">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="600" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <![endif]-->
        <table class="outer" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="full-width-image">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448299798/header-img_k75kme.jpg" width="600" alt="" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="three-column">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                <td width="200" valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <table class="column">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner">
                            <table class="contents">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448300038/shirts_hm4a61.jpg" width="180" alt="" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="btn-cell">
                                     <div><!--[if mso]>
                                      <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" strokecolor="#a8a8a8" fillcolor="#ffffff">
                                        <w:anchorlock/>
                                        <center style="color:#a8a8a8;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Shop Shirts</center>
                                      </v:rect>
                                    <![endif]--><a href="http://"
                                    style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #a8a8a8;color:#a8a8a8;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Shop Shirts</a></div>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td><td width="200" valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <table class="column">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner">
                            <table class="contents">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448300039/shoes_vhtq9j.jpg" width="180" alt="" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="btn-cell">
                                       <div><!--[if mso]>
                                          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" strokecolor="#a8a8a8" fillcolor="#ffffff">
                                            <w:anchorlock/>
                                            <center style="color:#a8a8a8;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Shop Shoes</center>
                                          </v:rect>
                                        <![endif]--><a href="http://"
                                        style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #a8a8a8;color:#a8a8a8;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Shop Shoes</a></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td><td width="200" valign="top">
                <![endif]-->
                <table class="column">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner">
                            <table class="contents">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448300039/accessories_dofp29.jpg" width="180" alt="" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="btn-cell">
                                        <div><!--[if mso]>
                                          <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" strokecolor="#a8a8a8" fillcolor="#ffffff">
                                            <w:anchorlock/>
                                            <center style="color:#a8a8a8;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Shop Accessories</center>
                                          </v:rect>
                                        <![endif]--><a href="http://"
                                        style="background-color:#ffffff;border:1px solid #A8A8A8;color:#A8A8A8;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Shop Accessories</a></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="one-column border">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="inner contents">
                                <p class="h1">Sign up now for weekly savings and deals</p>
                                <div class="signup-btn-div"><!--[if mso]>
                                  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#A8A8A8" fillcolor="#fff">
                                    <w:anchorlock/>
                                    <center style="color:#A8A8A8;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Subscribe</center>
                                  </v:roundrect>
                                <![endif]--><a href="http://"
                                style="background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #A8A8A8;border-radius:4px;color:#A8A8A8;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">SUBSCRIBE!</a></div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="one-column">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="inner contents">
                                 <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448313217/footer-img_zku5c5.jpg" width="600" alt="" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <!--  <tr>
                <td class="full-width-image">
                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448313217/footer-img_zku5c5.jpg" width="600" alt="" />
                </td>
            </tr> -->
            <tr>
                <td class="one-columns">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="inner contents">
                                <div class="social">
                                    <span><a href="#"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448313211/fb-icon_bgjpcc.png"></a></span>
                                    <span><a href="#"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448313215/youtube-icon_rqtuiv.png"></a></span>
                                    <span><a href="#"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448313215/twitter-icon_v4s0vo.png"></a></span>
                                    <span><a href="#"><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jet/image/upload/v1448313214/ig-icon_qxk3sl.png"></a></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="one-column">
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="inner contents">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <span><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></span>
                                    <span><a href="#">DOWNLOAD OUR APP</a></span>
                                    <span><a href="#">HELP</a></span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    Margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
    /*removes space under images in outlook*/
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.webkit {
    max-width: 600px;
}

.outer {
     Margin: 0 auto;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 600px;
}

.full-width-image img {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 600px;
     height: auto;
}

.inner {
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    Margin: 0;
}

a {
    color: #A8A8A8;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}

.social li {
   display: inline;
}
.input-div{
    text-align: center;
   Margin-left: auto;
   Margin-left: auto;
}
input[type="text"]{
   padding: 10px;
   line-height: 10px;
   width: 300px;
   text-align: center;
   Margin-left: auto;
   Margin-left: auto;
}

.h1 {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Margin-bottom: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}

.h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Margin-bottom: 12px;
}

/* One column layout */
.one-column .contents {
    text-align: center;
}
.one-column p {
    font-size: 14px;
    Margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/*Styles for three column*/

.three-column {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.three-column .column {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.three-column .contents {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.three-column img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}
.three-column .text {
    padding-top: 10px;
}



.btn-cell a {
    width: 180px;
    Margin-top: 10px;
}

.signup-btn-div {
   padding-top: 10px;
   text-align: center;
   Margin-left: auto;
   Margin-left: auto;
}

.border {
  border-top: solid 1px lightgray;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
}



.footer-img {
   padding-top: 10px;
}

.info span{
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}

.social{
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: MS-Outlook has a long tradition of being incompatible by purpose to other email clients. That was and is part of the MS strategy to keep people in their monopolies grip. So it is only consequent that outlook.com repeats the same behavior than the real email program. Otherwise the online version and the local version would be incompatible to each other, that would _really_ be funny then...

Comment: Any chance of posting your code? Would make it a lot easier to debug as I haven't seen anything like this before...

Comment: please post code - it is much easier to find solution when we have all the information.

Comment: Sorry about the late response guys,

Comment: The code is now up @Digital-Frankensteint